# Moving a limit inside integral and uniform convergence.

Tags: improper-integrals, uniform-convergence, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf, pointwise-convergence

I want to prove
$$ \lim_{\alpha\to0^+} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2x}{x^2+\alpha^2}=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}.$$
It seems trivial but I know that moving the limit inside the integral is not always allowed, but it should be allowed if the sequence of functions converge uniformly, if I am not mistaken. If $$f_n=\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2+n^2},$$ then to show show unifrom convergence:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lVert f_n-f \rVert=0.$$ I get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lVert \frac{\sin^2x}{x^2+n^2} -0\rVert=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup\rvert \frac{\sin^2x}{x^2+n^2}\lvert,$$ and this is where I am stuck. How do I find
$$\sup\rvert \frac{\sin^2x}{x^2+n^2}\lvert?$$

Comment: I'd rather use [monotone convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem). Uniform integrability is mostly useful when the domain of integration is bounded.

Comment: I don't see an $f$ in your norms.  Do you intend $f = 0$, i.e., $\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2+n^2} \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: I assumed that when n approaches infinity the hole expression would go to zero, correct?

Comment: Okay.  I would have instantly known that was what you meant if you had "$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left|\left| \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2+n^2} - 0 \right|\right|$".